# Auto Layout Max Width While Maintaining Divisibility

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'd like to use Auto Layout for my view to have the maximum width in it's superview while maintaining that the width is divisible by 7.

Answer (score 0):

Auto layout doesn't have direct support for divisibility. If you want it divisible by 7 because there are 7 sub-elements that you want equally sized and distributed, then you can set those constraints for the sub-elements and appropriate constraints relating the sub-elements to the containing view and you can achieve that.

If you don't naturally have such sub-elements, you can artificially add them just to achieve your divisible-by-7 requirement. You can add `UILayoutGuide`s (if targeting >=iOS 9.0) or hidden subviews (if targeting

Whether you naturally have such sub-elements or you're adding them just for this purpose, the approach is the same. Set constraints that they all have equal widths. Set constraints to put them in a row (trailing of one equals leading of the next). Set constraints to make their combined width equal to the containing view's width by setting the leading edge of the first equal to the leading edge of the container and the trailing edge of the last equal to the trailing edge of the container.

You will need to set *some* vertical constraints to dictate their vertical position and size, but those are relevant to this issue.

Now, set the constraints on the container relative to **its** superview. For example, constraints to center the container in its superview horizontally and vertically, plus a constraint to make the container's leading edge equal the superview's leading edge, but with a non-required priority (such as 900). It has to be non-required because it will sometimes have to be broken to maintain the centering and the divisible-by-7 width implied by the internal constraints. But, even when it has to be broken, the auto layout system will try to get it as close as possible, which is what makes the container as wide as possible.

You will also need a constraint that the leading edge of the container is greater than or equal to the leading edge of the superview, at required priority. That's because otherwise the auto layout system may make the container slightly wider than the superview if that's the closest it can get to being exactly as wide as the superview while maintaining the divisible-by-7 width.